# Changing function variable to another variable MATLAB

Tags: matlab

Is there a way to change a function variable to another variable?
for instance, if I have the function:

`f = @(s) exp(2-s)`

I need to change it to

`f = @(t) exp(2-t)`

without changing it manually.

Comment: Why would you want to do this? You call your function later as `f(1:10)`, or `my_variable = pi; f(my_variable)`. Why does the internal name of that function variable relevant? AFAIK there's no way to change this automatically, aside from using regex voodoo to read the .m file as text and change the variables within that.

Comment: "regex voodoo" would make for a very cool dub band name

Comment: Please provide more context.  This sounds like an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Answer (score 2):

**With the usual caveats that this is a terrible idea :) let's get a little nuts.**

First, we can make the anonymous function `f`

```
f = @(s) exp(2-s)
```

For some sample uses, for sanity

```
f(1)     % 2.71828182845905
f(10)    % 0.000335462627902512
```

Now, save it to a file, using the `-v7.3` flag to force an H5 file type

```
save('tempfile','f','-v7.3')
```

Matlab can read this file as data. After some exploring, we can see that the function is stored, as an evaluation-ready string, here:

```
char(h5read('tempfile.mat','/f/function_handle/function'))
%  Returns 'sf%0@(s)exp(2-s)'
```

So, it's easy enough to change, using Matlab's H5 write functions

```
h5write('tempfile.mat','/f/function_handle/function',uint16('sf%0@(x)exp(2-x)'))
```

Let's see, did it work?

```
clear f
load('tempfile.mat')
```

Now we have the following

```
f = 
  function_handle with value:
    @(x)exp(2-x)

f(1)   % 2.71828182845905
f(10)  % 0.000335462627902512
```

---

Now, we can see a lot of this data without the file saving business, using the `functions` function. (So meta)

```
>> f = @(s) exp(2-s);
>> functions(f)
ans = 
  struct with fields:

            function: '@(s)exp(2-s)'
                type: 'anonymous'
                file: ''
           workspace: {[1×1 struct]}
    within_file_path: '__base_function'
```

This lets you see how Matlab is storing the anonymous function. When debugging, this allows you to see what baggage (stored workspaces and stuff) is associated with the function handle.

However, changes to this structure do not change the actual function handle. I don't know of a way to generate a new function handle from this structure.

---

**Wrap up**

1. [note #1 deleted]
2. Please, don't ever do this.

Comment:  for putting that warning both at the top and the bottom of the post! :)

Comment: By the way, you can get a string of the anonymous function with `func2str(f)`. I'm guessing the only way to convert the modified string back to a function is through `eval`? Either way, doesn't matter, it's pointless to change the name of an internal variable. I'm wondering what OP thought this would help him with.

Comment: Looks like there is `str2func`. :)  `f = @(x)exp(2-x);` `str = func2str(f)` `g = str2func(str)`

Comment: The `functions` function is what I had remembered. I've added another section.

Comment: I was going to say `f2 = str2func(regexprep(func2str(f), '\<s\>', 'x', 'all'))`...

Comment: ... but yes, don't ever do this.

Comment: @Edric doesn't that turn `sin(s)` into `xin(x)` as well?

Comment: @Adriaan no - the `\<` and `\>` match word boundaries. Please note I am not claiming there are not bugs in my regexp - but that isn't one!